# Why Ngen didn't work when the code use Assembly.LoadFrom

Tags: c#, .net, performance, jit, ngen

I'm using ngen to install native image of an exe.
In the code i use Assembly.LoadFrom("MyLib.dll"), so i need also to install their dependencies.
I checked on Doc and i found

```
ngen install c:\myfiles\MyLib.dll /ExeConfig:c:\myapps\MyApp.exe
```

But it's not working the MyLib.dll is Compiled using Jit.
How we can resolve this ?

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.  Select the "Native images" category.

Comment: @HansPassant okey i'll look on it and see how i can resolve it.

Comment: @HansPassant All was succeed i don't have errors in my app but when i use perfmon and i check Jitted methods i see just methods from the external assembly importing using Assembly.loadFrom so how i can do Ngen also to this assembly ?